# How can I turn this into a for loop?

Tags: java

I am writing a Mastermind program in Java. So the user has to enter the number of pegs and colors and a code will randomly be generated and  the program will do its thing and tell them if they got the code or not. I have a bunch of IF statements and I tried putting it into a for loop so I don't have to create a if statement when the user increases the amt of pegs but that does not work. Any suggestion? Here is the code:

```
public void program(int [] peg, int amtpegs,int amtcolors) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
    int color = 0, guess = 1,pegs = 0;
    int [] guesses = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i<peg.length;i++) {
        
        
        
        peg[i]=generator.nextInt(amtpegs)+1;
        System.out.println(peg[i]);
    }
          //Repeat till the player wins
          while(true){
            //Get input from user
              for(int x = 0; x<amtpegs;x++)
                {
                  guesses[x]=reader.readInt("Enter your numbers: ");
                
                }
            //Check if peg in correct index
           for(int y = 0; y<amtpegs;y++) {
            if (peg[y]==guesses[y]){
              pegs++;
            
           }
            //Check if the color is correct
            if (guesses[0]==peg[0] || guesses[0]==peg[1] || guesses[0]==peg[2]){
              color++;
            }
            if (guesses[1]==peg[1] || guesses[1]==peg[0] || guesses[1]==peg[2]){
              color++;
            }
            if (guesses[2]==peg[0] || guesses[2]==peg[1] || guesses[2]==peg[2]){
              color++;
            }
            if (guesses[3]==peg[3] || guesses[3]==peg[1] || guesses[3]==peg[2]){
                  color++;
            }
                
            System.out.println("You have "+pegs+" correct peg(s) and "+color+" correct colors");
            //Exit if player wins
            if (color==amtcolors && pegs==amtpegs){
              System.out.println("You have broken the code in "+guess+" guesses");
              break;
            }
            //Increment guess count
            guess++;
            //Reset the color and peg value
            color=0;
            pegs=0;
            
          
          }
```

i tried making the if or statements into a for loop by replacing the indexes with the x and j in the for loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x<amtpegs;x++) {
              // System.out.println(x+"n");
               for(int j = 0; j<amtpegs; j++){
                //   System.out.println(j+"N");
                 if (guesses[x]==peg[j]){
                   color++;
                   if (color==amtcolors && pegs==amtpegs){
                      System.out.println("You have broken the code in "+guess+" guesses");
                      break;
                    }
                 }
```

but that does not work since my variable colors increases in values. EX: If i input 10 pegs and 9 colors it will come out a 10 pegs and 20 or 30 colors.

Answer (score -1):

Your pattern here:

```
//Check if the color is correct
if (guesses[0]==peg[0] || guesses[0]==peg[1] || guesses[0]==peg[2]){
    color++;
}
if (guesses[1]==peg[1] || guesses[1]==peg[0] || guesses[1]==peg[2]){
    color++;
}
if (guesses[2]==peg[0] || guesses[2]==peg[1] || guesses[2]==peg[2]){
    color++;
}
if (guesses[3]==peg[3] || guesses[3]==peg[1] || guesses[3]==peg[2]){
    color++;
}
```

Is to loop over guesses not pegs. Your for loop is close and just needs to be adjusted so you are not looping over pegs as well:

```
for(int x = 0; x<guesses.lengh;x++)
    if (guesses[x]==peg[0] || guesses[x]==peg[1] || guesses[x]==peg[2]){
        color++;
}
```

*Edit I noticed that I used the `atmpegs`. If we are just varying guesses then it should be the length of the guesses array.

If you want to work with an array of guesses and array of pegs of variable length then you would nest and loop on the guess array and the pegs array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < peg.length; j++)
    {
         if(guesses[i] == peg[j])
             color++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that works a bit, but peg[index] increases or decreases depending on the amount of pegs the user enters. How would I incorp. that into the loop?

Comment: I tried doing a nested for loop but that doubles my variable "colors" when it prints out.

Comment: The same issue still occurs, if i enter in 10 pegs and 9 colors. The output is 10 pegs and 28 colors.